# How to upload photo via angular to Web API and add that photo with other values to a new object from a class

Tags: c#, angular

So, I am making an application with angular and an .NET API. I want people to upload images with some text (for example. Name, City, etc.). I already found a way to upload the image from my angular frontend to my backend. The problem is that, when I put the image selector in a form with some other input fields, I get a Bad Request. To make things more clear please look at the code. Thank you for your help.

On the link below you can find a photo of how I store the uploaded images. So if the uploading works there must be a way to actually add those photos to the other values and generate a card. I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGvDv.jpg

On these 2 links you can see what I want as input and then what to do with the input. https://i.stack.imgur.com/49GbZ.jpg (form)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCoJL.jpg  (result)

This is my card constructor from my Card class

```
       {
           Provincie = provincie;
           Postcode = postcode;
           Stad = stad;
           Photo = photo;
           Text = text;
           Likes = likes;
           Moeilijkheidsgraad = moeilijkheidsgraad;
       }
```

This is my Post method to make a new Card:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<Card> PostCard(CardDTO card)
        {
            Card cardToCreate = new Card() { Provincie = card.Provincie, Postcode = card.Postcode,
                Stad = card.Stad , Text = card.Text, Photo= card.Photo, Likes = card.Likes, Moeilijkheidsgraad = card.Moeilijkheidsgraad};
            _cardRepository.Add(cardToCreate);
            _cardRepository.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetCard), new { id = cardToCreate.CardId }, cardToCreate);
        }
```

This is my onSubmit() so when the form is filled in and pressed

```
  onSubmit() {
    this._cardDataService.uploadFile(this.add.value.image.files);


    this._cardDataService
      .addNewRecipe(new Card(this.add.value.provincie, this.add.value.postcode, this.add.value.stad,
      this.add.value.text,  this.add.value.image.files,  0, this.add.value.moeilijkheidsgraad)).subscribe();
    this.submitted = true;
    // this.add.reset();
    // this.removeImage();
  }
```

This is my connection to the post method in my backend.

```
  addNewRecipe(card:Card) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/Card`, card.toJSON());
  }
```

This is how i send an image to my backend

```
  public uploadFile = (files) => {
    if (files.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let fileToUpload = <File>files[0];
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

    this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/Upload`, formData, {reportProgress: true, observe: 'events'})
      .subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
          this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.message = 'Upload success.';
          this.onUploadFinished.emit(event.body);
        }
      });
    }
```

This is the API upload method

```
 [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            try
            {
                var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
                var folderName = Path.Combine("wwwroot","Resources", "Images");
                var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                    var fullPath = Path.Combine(pathToSave, fileName);
                    var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }

                    return Ok(new { dbPath });
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: of what type is `Photo` in the `Card` class?

Comment: Are you providing multipart/formdata to the form data ?

Comment: @Taher photo is of type string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on `onSubmit` method, you are uploading the file first and then send it to the server with the form again, where in the backend as you said the `Photo` property is string, so you are getting `Bad request`.

1. When you upload the photo and save it successfully, let the server return the `PhtotPath` as `response`.
2. now send the `PhtotPath` with the form values to the server.

```
onSubmit() {
  // it should be array when you have multiple photos
  let photoPath;
  this._cardDataService.uploadFile(this.add.value.image.files).subscribe(res => {
    // the response from the api should have the photoPath
      photoPath = res.dbPath;
      this._cardDataService.addNewRecipe(
        new Card(this.add.value.provincie, this.add.value.postcode,
         this.add.value.stad, this.add.value.text, photoPath, 0, 
         this.add.value.moeilijkheidsgraad)).subscribe(res => {
              this.submitted = true;
         });

  });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, The only question I have now is how can you return that photopath as a response ? Because I thought i had it done?

Comment: I added the API upload method could you check it out for me @Taher

Comment: the Api seems to be fine! I've just updated the answer.
Does the Api returns an object like this `{'dbPath': 'wwwroot/resources...'}`

Comment: no it doesn't I think. How can i do this and where?

Comment: What is the response when you subscribe the `uploadFile` method? please, `console.log(res)` before `photoPath = res.dbPath;` and let me now what are you getting.

Comment: please expand the `HttpResponse` object :)

Comment: https://imgur.com/WKoezbZ here you go mate. I want to thank you aswell in advance for your patience

Comment: You are getting the `dbPath` in the body of `HttpResponse` , so we are good :D . So you need to extract it now :) But your `CardDataService` should be updated! can you show me the `addNewRecipe` method in `CardDataService`.

Comment: addNewCard(provincie: string,postcode:number, stad:string, text:string,photo:string, moeilijkheidsgraad:string) {
    return this.http.post(`${environment.apiUrl}/Card`,{provincie,postcode,stad,text,photo,moeilijkheidsgraad});
  }

Comment: Interesting! then just extract the `res` like this `res.HttpResponse.body.dbPath`.

Comment: please accept the answer! If it solves the issue :)